# Check java component is empty

Tags: java, components, is-empty

Why if doesn' work when check if component is equal to ""

```
  private boolean ControllaCampi(){
        boolean verifica = true;
        for (Component component : pMain.getComponents()){
        if ((component.getClass().equals(JTextField.class)) ||  component.getClass().equals(JFormattedTextField.class))){
            if (component.equals("")){
                verifica = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return verifica;
}
```

Comment: Because the component isn't a String!

Comment: How i can check if is empty???

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the component isn't a String!

To check if the component is empty, you can do:

```
if (component.getComponentCount()==0){
    verifica = false;
    break;
}
```

Comment: I saw that getComponentCount is deprecated

Comment: Well, as far as I know, `countComponents()` has been deprecated and replaced by `getComponentCount()`.  I have never seen that `getComponentCount()` has been deprecated. Are you sure that it is?

Comment: That's wrong. `getComponentCount()` returns the number of child components of the component.

Comment: @andrucz Exactly... And when it is 0, then the component is empty!

Comment: But I believe he wants to check if the component text is equals to "".

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing oranges to apples. `Component` can't be compared with `""`, which is a `String` instance. You have to get the text to check whether it is empty or not:

```
String componentText = component.getText();
if (componentText.equals("")) {
    ...
}
```

Also, you can replace `component.getClass().equals(...)` to `component instanceof JTextField`. It will return `true` to both `JTextField` and `JFormattedTextField` (which is a subclass of `JTextField`).